# Cover the touch area that is overlapped by another layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to show a layout on top of another layout that is in full screen, but when I touch the laout that in on top (higher **translationZ**) the view that is behind this layout also get clicked. I want the view that is in behind have touch gesture but I don't want touch gesture when I click the viewholder that is on top.

Also when I use AppBarLayout then there is no problem, but when I use ConstraintLayout, I am not able to fix the problem.

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clBigScreenPhotoInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:translationZ="1dp"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:background="#77000000"
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="72dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivBack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_white" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="#77000000"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBig"
            android:translationZ="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/big"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

click listener of the imageView that is in behind

```
binding.ivBig.setOnClickListener {
    val v = binding.clBigScreenPhotoInfo
    if (v.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
        v.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        return
    }
    v.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

Comment: Instead of using android:translationZ, use elevation

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim I tried :( it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post the onClick methods to see ?

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim I added in the question now

Comment: add this yourFullScreenImage.setClickable(false), to provide only click to the top and bottom layout

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim But I want the touch gesture at rest of the part that is not covered

Comment: I am not sure that I follow your question. Try setting `android:clickable="true"` for the bottom _ConstraintLayout_ to see if that works for you. (Don't set a click listener to it though.)